Deploying a Phoenix Application with a Postgres database
I am trying to deploy a Phoenix app with a Postgres database on Docker. I also intend to use Nginx as my reverse proxy ( but this is not the main agenda). So I have been using Phoenix Releases but somehow I have failed to run mix phx.server to start the system. Here is my Dockerfile :
# Find eligible builder and runner images on Docker Hub. We use Ubuntu/Debian
# instead of Alpine to avoid DNS resolution issues in production.
#
# https://hub.docker.com/r/hexpm/elixir/tags?page=1&name=ubuntu
# https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu?tab=tags
#
# This file is based on these images:
#
#   - https://hub.docker.com/r/hexpm/elixir/tags - for the build image
#   - https://hub.docker.com/_/debian?tab=tags&page=1&name=bullseye-20240701-slim - for the release image
#   - https://pkgs.org/ - resource for finding needed packages
#   - Ex: hexpm/elixir:1.17.2-erlang-27.0-debian-bullseye-20240701-slim
#
ARG ELIXIR_VERSION=1.17.2
ARG OTP_VERSION=27.0
ARG DEBIAN_VERSION=bullseye-20240701-slim

ARG BUILDER_IMAGE="hexpm/elixir:${ELIXIR_VERSION}-erlang-${OTP_VERSION}-debian-${DEBIAN_VERSION}"
ARG RUNNER_IMAGE="debian:${DEBIAN_VERSION}"

FROM ${BUILDER_IMAGE} as builder

# install build dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y build-essential git \
    && apt-get clean && rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*_*

# prepare build dir
WORKDIR /app

# install hex + rebar
RUN mix local.hex --force && \
    mix local.rebar --force

# set build ENV
ENV MIX_ENV="prod"

# install mix dependencies
COPY mix.exs mix.lock ./
RUN mix deps.get --only $MIX_ENV
RUN mkdir config

# copy compile-time config files before we compile dependencies
# to ensure any relevant config change will trigger the dependencies
# to be re-compiled.
COPY config/config.exs config/${MIX_ENV}.exs config/
RUN mix deps.compile

COPY priv priv

COPY lib lib

COPY run.sh ./

COPY assets assets

# compile assets
RUN mix assets.deploy

# Compile the release
RUN mix compile

# Changes to config/runtime.exs don't require recompiling the code
COPY config/runtime.exs config/

COPY rel rel
RUN mix release

# start a new build stage so that the final image will only contain
# the compiled release and other runtime necessities
FROM ${RUNNER_IMAGE}

RUN apt-get update -y && \
  apt-get install -y libstdc++6 openssl libncurses5 locales ca-certificates \
  && apt-get clean && rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*_*

# Set the locale
RUN sed -i '/en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //g' /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

WORKDIR "/app"
RUN chown nobody /app

# set runner ENV
ENV MIX_ENV="prod"

# Only copy the final release from the build stage
COPY --from=builder --chown=nobody:root /app/_build/${MIX_ENV}/rel/my_app ./

USER nobody

EXPOSE 4000

# If using an environment that doesn't automatically reap zombie processes, it is
# advised to add an init process such as tini via `apt-get install`
# above and adding an entrypoint. See https://github.com/krallin/tini for details
# ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--"]

CMD ["/app/bin/server"]


I want a way I can run the server using mix phx.server . Currently what i have done is this which does not work since there is the error saying
mix not found 

I wrote this run.sh file and made it executable :

#!/bin/sh
# Adapted from Alex Kleissner's post, Running a Phoenix 1.3 project with docker-compose
# https://medium.com/@hex337/running-a-phoenix-1-3-project-with-docker-compose-d82ab55e43cf

set -e


# Ensure the app's dependencies are installed
mix deps.get

# Prepare Dialyzer if the project has Dialyxer set up
if mix help dialyzer >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  echo "\nFound Dialyxer: Setting up PLT..."
  mix do deps.compile, dialyzer --plt
else
  echo "\nNo Dialyxer config: Skipping setup..."
fi

# Install JS libraries
echo "\nInstalling JS..."
cd assets && npm install
cd ..

# Wait for Postgres to become available.
until psql -h db -U "postgres" -c '\q' 2>/dev/null; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

echo "\nPostgres is available: continuing with database setup..."

#Analysis style code
# Prepare Credo if the project has Credo start code analyze
if mix help credo >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  echo "\nFound Credo: analyzing..."
  mix credo || true
else
  echo "\nNo Credo config: Skipping code analyze..."
fi

# Potentially Set up the database
mix ecto.create
mix ecto.migrate

echo "\nTesting the installation..."
# "Prove" that install was successful by running the tests
mix test

echo "\n Launching Phoenix web server..."
# Start the phoenix web server
mix phx.server


And then attached it to the docker-compose.yml

version: "3.2"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:16.0-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_EXTENSIONS: citext ,uuid-ossp
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /app
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    environment:
      # Modify your config files (dev.exs and test.exs) so that the password and hostname can be overridden
      # when environment variables are set:
      # password: System.get_env("DB_PASS", "postgres"),
      # hostname: System.get_env("DB_HOST", "localhost"),
      - DB_PASS=
      - DB_HOST=db
    depends_on:
      - db
    command:
      - ./run.sh



Kindly point out where you think i am going wrong so i immediately change it .
Or Provide an alternative way of Dockerizing this application
Thank you.

You are using Phoenix's standard Docker setup.  This is on the whole a pretty reasonable Docker setup.  Reading through that entire page is helpful background.
One non-obvious point here is that the container's default command just runs the generated release script, but that has several subcommands.  In practice you probably want the /app/server/bin start subcommand.
All mix phx.server actually does is to start your application with the Phoenix Web server enabled.  You might not want it turned on, say, for mix test.  As the documentation notes, if your config.exs includes config Phoenix.Endpoint, server: true then starting your main application normally will also start the server.
The Phoenix new-application boilerplate includes this fragment (where app_name and endpoint_module come from parameters to mix phx.new):
# If you use `mix release`, you need to explicitly enable the server
# by passing the PHX_SERVER=true when you start it:
#
#     PHX_SERVER=true bin/<%= @app_name %> start
#
# Alternatively, you can use `mix phx.gen.release` to generate a `bin/server`
# script that automatically sets the env var above.
if System.get_env("PHX_SERVER") do
  config :<%= @app_name %>, <%= @endpoint_module %>, server: true
end

If your config/runtime.exs has this fragment, then it's enough to

Set the environment variable PHX_SERVER=true, and
Run the server script the release generates with an argument start.

...
ENV PHX_SERVER=true
CMD ["/app/bin/server", "start"]

(This Dockerfile for a personal project is a little more involved – in particular, I've split out a Web server, data store, and worker container – but for the Web container I similarly set PHX_SERVER=true and run the start command.)

And what do you think of my docker compose. Can it be a source of issue because currently the server still doesn't start but the database is started

I am getting this error on the logs            /app/bin/server: not found

Definitely delete the volumes: block, it's almost certainly causing that problem.  You should also be able to delete the command: override.
